# Instance of List mess upp values

Tags: c#

I've a list in a class:

```
public class LogInList
{
    public int AnsNr { get; set; }

    public List<LogInList> GetNr()
    {
        List<LogInList> Nr = new List<LogInList>();
        Nr.Add(new LogInList { AnsNr = 101 });

        return Nr;
    }

}
```

And I've created a instance of it in my Login form:

```
public partial class LogIn : Form
{
    LogInList Log = new LogInList();
```

**AND** in my button in the form I've the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inMatningTextBox.Text == Log.AnsNr.ToString())
        {
            Ö.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Du har skrivit in fel anställningsnummer!");
        }
```

The thing is, the int value of 'AnsNr' is automatically changed from 101 to 0 when the program starts. I guess that the new Instance is responsible for this? It tracks back to how many Items there is in the list, I guess? How do I go around this? I want to be able to enter '101' to login.. not 0 ;)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are never calling the `GetNr` method of `LogInList`, but access the member `AnsNr` which is (implicitly) initialized with `0`.

Perhaps you can achieve your goal using

```
if ( Log.GetNr().Select( entry => entry.AnsNr ).Contains( Convert.ToInt32( inMatningTextBox.Text ) ) )
{
    Ö.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

where you would also have to use

```
include System.Linq;
```

Comment: How would I do to call the GetNr method?

Comment: Sadly, it doesnt work.. I get errors like 'cannot convert from 'int' to 'PKS_FinalVersion.LogInList' and if I take away the () after Log.GetNr I get error: 'PKS_FinalVersion.LogInList.GetNr()' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context..

Comment: Okay, I don't get any error and can run the program. But it still doesn't respond to '101'.. :o

Answer (score 0):

When you create your form you have this code:

```
LogInList Log = new LogInList();
```

It simply creates an instance of `LogInList` and does not set the value of `AnsNr`.

Your code doesn't show a call to `GetNr`, but if it is called there is a second instance of `LogInList` created and that one does set the value of `AnNr` to 101.

The first instance value of `AnsNr` is never set, that's the problem with your code.

Comment: Okay, thanks for you answer. I'm pretty new to all this, how would I call the GetNr method?